# Get dummies for ordinal variables and change column names automatically?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing these in python, but I thought maybe there is a faster way to do this.

After doing `pd.get_dummies(dataset[a column name])` for ordinal variables, I'm manually checking number of columns and putting 1, 2, 3,.. at the end of each new column names.

In python, could we write more efficient codes so that python gets dummies for ordinal variables and rename column names with numbers attached in order? (i.e. if I give g, it renames columns as g1, g2, g3 columns)

```
dummie_g = pd.get_dummies(d["gen"])
dummie_g.describe()
dummie_g.columns = ['g1','g2','g3']

dummie_e=pd.get_dummies(d["educ"])
dummie_e.describe()
dummie_e.columns = ['e1','e2','e3','e4']

dummie_a=pd.get_dummies(d["type"])
dummie_a.describe()
dummie_a.columns=['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6']

dummie_n=pd.get_dummies(d["name"])
dummie_n.describe()
dummie_n.columns=['n1','n2']

dummie_dpt=pd.get_dummies(d["dpt"])
dummie_dpt.describe()
dummie_dpt.columns=['h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6','h7','h8','h9','h10','h11','h12','h13','h14','h15']
```

Comment: can you make your code example runnable in isolation? something one can copy, paste and execute?

Comment: @glor you can mark the answer as accepted or comment what went wrong.

Comment: @Dark  sry guys didn't know I could select an answer! Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @Evgeny I will write something executable next time. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @glor you can vote on the answer too :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a parameter called `prefix` for `get_dummies` to add the prefix for the columns after getting dummies. You can use it like

```
pd.get_dummies(d["gen"],prefix='g')
```

An improved version of you code might be :

```
dfs = {}
# use dicts over repeating n varaibles. 
for i,j in zip(["gen","educ","type","name","dpt"],["g","e","a","n","h"]):
    dfs['dummies_'+j] = pd.get_dummies(d[i],prefix=j)
```